# thimbleberry leaf browning

Tags: diagnosis, diseases

I have a young thimbleberry that I planted this past spring. It has been growing well and seemed to be getting established. Now I am seeing some leaf browning. We are in Denver and it has been hot and dry for the past 4 weeks. I have been watering at night about twice a week.

Browning occurs around the edges of some leaves as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the plant is in full sun and its very hot, the leaves are being scorched - in the wild, this plant prefers to grow in dappled or partial shade, with some full sun maybe late afternoon/evening or early morning, in cooler, more temperate conditions. If you can provide some shade for it between 11 and 2 pm, that should help, otherwise, all you can do is keep it well watered. https://www.fs.fed.us/wildflowers/plant-of-the-week/rubus_parviflorus.shtml